Setting User input as a workbook
I am very very new to VBA and have not been able to find a solution to the problem that I am running into.
I have written a macro to take the last line of data from a folder of workbooks and put them into an active workbook. But now I am trying to add in a user specificed workbook as the destination for this copied data.
'Need help setting the user input string as the name of the workbook
Dim inputData As Variant
Dim userBook As Workbook
Dim destBook As Workbook
   
    'Get name of final destination Workbook
    inputData = InputBox("Enter the name of the destination workbook")
    
    'Set the user input as place holder workbook variable
    Set userBook = inputData
    
    'Set your master workbook as the placeholder workbook
    Set destBook = userBook

I think I either 1) need a way to change the type that the variable inputData is storing originally but am unsure which type would work for my purposes, or 2) only run the macro in the destination workbook.
The whole macro is here as well in case there is some other interference that I missed when trying to make changes.
Sub Copying()
'
' Copying Macro
'

Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Dim CopyLastRow As Long
Dim fileName As String
Dim sheetName As String
Dim folderPath As String
Dim lastRow As Long

'Need help setting the user input string as the name of the workbook
Dim inputData As Variant
Dim userBook As Workbook
Dim destBook As Workbook
   
    'Get name of final destination Workbook
    inputData = InputBox("Enter the name of the destination workbook")
    
    'Set the user input as place holder workbook variable
    Set userBook = inputData
    
    'Set your master workbook as the placeholder workbook
    Set destBook = userBook
    
    
    
    
    'Set the master "Data" worksheet
    Set destSheet = destBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Specify the folder path where your source workbooks are located
    folderPath = "C:\Users\USKAALV1\Documents\FlexLogger\data\"

    'Get the file name from the folder
    fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.csv")

Do While fileName <> ""
        'Get the sheet name from the file name
        sheetName = Left(fileName, Len(fileName) - 4)
    
        'Open the workbook
        Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileName)
        
        'Set the source worksheet
        Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets(sheetName)
        
        'Find the last used row in the source worksheet
        lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Copy range from source worksheet
        sourceSheet.Range("A" & lastRow & ":D" & lastRow).Copy
        
        'Find the last row in the master "Data" sheet
        lastRow = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Paste into the master "Data" worksheet
        destSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        'Clear clipboard
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        'Close the source workbook without saving
        sourceBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
        'Cycle to the next file in the folder
        fileName = Dir
Loop
    


This question is similar to: Open a Workbook with Path and Filename Stored in String Variables. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Where do you keep the code? In PERSONAL.xlsb? Has the active workbook ever been saved i.e. does it have a path (e.g. C:\Test\Test.xlsx) or was it just created?

@VBasic2008, currently the code is just stored in a blank test workbook that I've been using with a collection of simulated source files. I'm not sure if that answers your question.  I originally was looking to define an existing file as the destination, but I am also open to creating a new file with the specified name if that will be easier with the code I already have in place

I assume the destination workbook is located in the same folder as ThisWorkbook (where the code is stored).
GetWK() is used to get the dest. workbook.
Option Explicit

Sub Copying()
    Dim sourceBook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet
    Dim CopyLastRow As Long
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    'Need help setting the user input string as the name of the workbook
    Dim inputData As String
    Dim userBook As Workbook
    Dim destBook As Workbook
    
    'Get name of final destination Workbook
    inputData = InputBox("Enter the name of the destination workbook")
    If Len(inputData) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please input the source file."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Set your master workbook as the placeholder workbook
    Set destBook = GetWK(inputData)  ' ***
    
    'Set the master "Data" worksheet
    Set destSheet = destBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Specify the folder path where your source workbooks are located
    folderPath = "C:\Users\USKAALV1\Documents\FlexLogger\data\"
    
    'Get the file name from the folder
    fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.csv")
    
    Do While fileName <> ""
        'Get the sheet name from the file name
        sheetName = Left(fileName, Len(fileName) - 4)
        
        'Open the workbook
        Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileName)
        
        'Set the source worksheet
        Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets(sheetName)
        
        'Find the last used row in the source worksheet
        lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Copy range from source worksheet
        sourceSheet.Range("A" & lastRow & ":D" & lastRow).Copy
        
        'Find the last row in the master "Data" sheet
        lastRow = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        If lastRow = 2 And Len(destSheet.Cells(1, 1)) = 0 Then lastRow = 1 ' ** blank sheet
        
        'Paste into the master "Data" worksheet
        destSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        'Clear clipboard
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        'Close the source workbook without saving
        sourceBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
        'Cycle to the next file in the folder
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
    
End Sub

Function GetWK(sWB As String) As Workbook
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Const EXT_NAME = ".xlsx"  ' modify as needed
    If LCase(Right(sWB, Len(EXT_NAME))) <> EXT_NAME Then
        sWB = sWB & EXT_NAME ' add extension name
    End If
    ' check if the dest. workbook is opened in Excel
    For Each wk In Application.Workbooks
        If UCase(wk.Name) = UCase(sWB) Then
            Set GetWK = wk
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    If GetWK Is Nothing Then
        Dim sFile As String: sFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sWB
        If Len(Dir(sFile)) = 0 Then
            Set wk = Application.Workbooks.Add ' create a new Excel file
            wk.SaveAs sFile
        Else ' open existing file
            Set wk = Application.Workbooks.Open(sFile)
        End If
        Set GetWK = wk
    End If
End Function



Im actually looking for the opposite. The source files are already accounted for and able to be found because of the way the data program outputs them as csv files. What I am trying to do is have the user define where they want the data to go. Example: create a new document called"Report 3" instead of having data dump into where the macro is running, ie. ThisWorkbook/ActiveWorkbook

Is 'Report 3' a file name? sheet name?

Report 3 would be the file name in this case

GetWK() is used to get the dest. workbook.

This fixed the problem I was having! Thank you so much.

It's a good news.

Copy Last Row Values from Closed Workbooks
Sub ImportLastRows()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Import Last Rows"
    Const SRC_FOLDER_PATH As String = _
        "C:\Users\USKAALV1\Documents\FlexLogger\data\"
    Const SRC_FILE_PATTERN As String = "*.csv"
    Const SRC_COPY_COLUMNS As String = "A:D"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    
    ' Reference the destination workbook.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If this is the workbook containing this code, use 'ThisWorkbook'.
    
    ' Retrieve the user input (a valid file name is expected).
    Dim InputString As String: InputString = _
        InputBox("Enter the name of the destination workbook", PROC_TITLE)
    If Len(InputString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Operation cancelled!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Retrieve the first file name.
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(SRC_FOLDER_PATH & "*.csv")
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files matching the pattern """ & SRC_FILE_PATTERN _
            & """ found in """ & SRC_FOLDER_PATH & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    If dws.FilterMode Then dws.ShowAllData
    
    ' Reference the first available destination (single-row) range.
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long:
    ColumnsCount = dws.Columns(SRC_COPY_COLUMNS).Columns.Count
    Dim drrg As Range, dlcell As Range
    With dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS).Resize(, ColumnsCount)
        With .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
            Set dlcell = .Find( _
                What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        End With
        If dlcell Is Nothing Then
            Set drrg = .Cells
        Else
            Set drrg = .Offset(dlcell.Row - .Row + 1)
        End If
    End With
         
    ' Loop through the source files and copy each bottom-most
    ' populated row to the next destination row.
    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, srrg As Range, slcell As Range
    Dim dRow As Long
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        ' Reference the source objects.
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(SRC_FOLDER_PATH & sFileName)
        Set sws = swb.Sheets(1) ' the one an only ('.csv')
        Set srrg = Nothing
        With sws.Columns(SRC_COPY_COLUMNS)
            Set slcell = .Find( _
                What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not slcell Is Nothing Then
                Set srrg = .Rows(1).Offset(slcell.Row - .Row)
            End If
        End With
        ' Copy values.
        If Not srrg Is Nothing Then
            drrg.Offset(dRow).Value = srrg.Value
            dRow = dRow + 1
        End If
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        sFileName = Dir ' next file name
    Loop
    
    ' Here goes the code to save the destination workbook.
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox dRow & " last row" & IIf(dRow = 1, "", "s") & " imported.", _
        IIf(dRow = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation), PROC_TITLE
    
End Sub

